# ArrayList & LinkedList Stack Implementation

Tags: arraylist, linked-list, stack, containers

I have written two implementations of Stack based on interface below

```
public interface Stack<T>{
   public void push(T t);
   public T pop();
   public boolean isEmpty();
}
```

First implementation uses ArrayList as container for elements, while second implementation uses LinkedList. Is it better to have separate implementations for every underlying container or have only one stack implementation which is independent of the container?

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Before answer your question, when you used interface, add 'I' before your interface name, such as: IStack

When you use interface for each class, which implement your attention, of course, you must re-write interface's methods for each class. Because, interface didn't implement there methods until interface is inherited by some classes not mention implemtation of containers have different .

Example:

```
class YourStackOne<T>: IStack<T>
{
//Container
LinkedLink<T> ContainElement;

public void push(T t){//implementation for YourStackOne..}
public T pop(){//implementation for YourStackOne..}
public boolean isEmpty{//implementation for YourStackOne..}
}

class YourStackTwo: IStack<int>
{
//Container
ArrayList ContainElement;

public void push(int t){//implementation for YourStackTwo..}
public int pop(){//implementation for YourStackTwo..}
public boolean isEmpty{//implementation for YourStackTwo..}
}
```

By the way, if you're writing in .NET, why don't you use Stack class?

Answer (score 0):

If one implementation is better than other for different situations, you should have both implementation.

But, in case of stack, if you have just push(), pop(), and isEmpty(), either LinkedList or ArrayList will not be superior to the other in terms of time complexity. So, you can just have one implementation of your choosing.

Constant time complexity for push(), pop(), and isEmpty():

Using ArrayList: Always add to the bottom of the list, and remove from bottom.

Using LinkedList: Always add to the front of the list and remove from front.